# Access files in home folder with PHP (linux)

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a php application located in **/var/www/phpapp** and I need to create links to download files located in the **/home/myuser** folder. The complete path to the files is stored in a database, so the goal is for the app to place a link like `<a href="/home/myuser/file1.doc">Download 1</a>` and be able to download it. I access the php app using http://localhost/phpapp. I know I can do this using alias in apache but I still haven't figure it out.

Comment: you cant directly link to them if that folder is outside the webroot .. you either have to move the files, symlink the files, or best option access(serve) them via a php script

Comment: With Apache an `Alias` directive might make sense. But rather not for the whole home directory.

Comment: In the apache docs they explain how to achieve this, but I haven't been able to do it. Here's the link [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this same problem, I got it working using this:

- In Ubuntu: I went to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ and edit the site file
- In Centos: Go to /etc/httpd/conf.d/ and add a new xxxx.conf file

And I added this into the file:

```
Alias /home "/home/user/"
<Directory "/home/user">
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks 
    MultiViews Require all granted
</Directory>
```